# "Match companies and seekers better"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, grammar

When I clicked "not interested" to a message in Careers, I was given this amusing instruction (emphasis mine):

> Can you tell us why you're not interested in this job inquiry? This information is only used internally to help us to **better** match companies and job seekers **better**.

I think just one "better" is enough in that sentence.  Keep whichever one you prefer.

Comment: Personally, I prefer leaving out the last "better": _This information is only used internally to help us to better match companies and job seekers_.

Comment: Who writes these things? There's also everything-is-lowercase problems everywhere.

Comment: @bjb568 If you see things like that, please don't hesitate to bring them up in a question here. We'd love to get any inaccuracies fixed.

Comment: @rossipedia I'm question banned here. Anyway, "flag this question" instead of "Flag this question". "feed of this question" instead of "Feed of this question". "site design / logo © 2014 stack exchange inc  user contributions licensed..." instead of "Site design and logo © 2014 Stack Exchange inc; User contributions licensed..."

Comment: "possible duplicate" instead of "Possible duplicate"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, that is an odd turn of phrase. I went ahead and removed the second "better". It should now read:

> This information is only used internally to help us to better match companies and job seekers.

Comment: Much better ...